# 'Des' before an adjective before a noun

Tags: de

I came across this sentence in an article:

> Les utilisateurs de jets privés sont donc des gros pollueurs

I would have expected the phrase to be '**de** gros pollueurs'.

Are my expectations too formal? Or does the use of 'des' in fact carry a different meaning or nuance?

Comment: It is gramatically incorrect. But as French, I believe to use that when I want to add emphasis on the plural "all of them are".

Answer (score 4):

1. *Are my expectations too formal ?*

   Not "too" formal, ***de*** would fit a large range of registers, from formal to casual, both oral and written.
2. *Or does the use of 'des' in fact carry a different meaning or nuance?*

   The meaning is the same. Using ***des*** is just relaxed French but it can be heard and sometimes read without raising eyebrows:

   > ***Ce sont des gros chats** qu'on ne s'attend pas à croiser dans nos forêts de Côte-d'Or !* [France Bleu](https://www.francebleu.fr/infos/environnement/quelques-lynx-dans-les-forets-de-cote-d-or-1641492175)

   > *Autre point de vigilance pour vos premiers cours et évaluations : votre orthographe. Dans la continuité du lycée, les professeurs relèvent le niveau d'exigence sur la correction des copies. "L'orthographe, le vocabulaire, la syntaxe et la grammaire **sont des gros soucis**", note Matthieu Boisdron.*  [L'Étudiant](https://www.letudiant.fr/etudes/fac/premiers-pas-a-la-fac-les-bons-reflexes.html), sept. 2015.

   Maybe ***des*** is also sometimes preferred to avoid the ambiguity of ***de*** when it might be confused with *deux*, as they are pronounced identically.

   @Jeffrey commented that he would use ***des*** in the following sentence and I agree with him:

   > *Il y avait **des** petits bouleaux devant la maison*.

   The alternate form is clearly ambiguous orally:

   > *Il y avait **de** petits bouleaux devant la maison* (?) or ***deux** petits bouleaux* ?

   Not to mention *de petits bouleaux* sounds like a much more common collocation: *de petits boulots*.

   Another case where ***des*** is almost always used used instead of ***de*** is before *petit trous*, for example in the famous song *[Le poinçonneur des Lilas](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Poin%C3%A7onneur_des_Lilas)*:

   > [Je fais des trous, des petits trous, encore des petits trous](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eWkWCFzkOvU&t=31s)

   Here, a possible explanation is that ***petit trou*** is considered a single "word". That's the reason why the sentence *Je mange **de** petits pois* is never used.*

Comment: Is *-s* omitted here, because the plural marker *-s* is already present in the adjective?  I am trying to make an analogy with German, where the adjective endings depend on whether the noun group is preceded by an article and whether the article already contains an unambiguous case/number marker.

Comment: @RogerVadim Not sure if the plural marker makes a difference. Note also that a similar thing happen in negative sentences:  *J'ai **des** lunettes* → *Je n'ai pas **de** lunettes*.

Answer (score 1):

*Des* may mean different things:

- preposition *de*, which can be joined with plural definite article *les* as *de + les = des*
- plural indefinite article *des*
- plural partitive article (aka *some of the...*)

Here preposition *de* is not needed, so *des* is in fact the mixture of the last two bullets. It could be interpreted as partitive, given that *les utilisateurs de jets privés* are not the only *gros pollueurs*, but only a part of a larger group. However, one also needs an article in an "equation" phrase, when the predicate contains an adjective:
*il est pollueur* -> *il est un gros pollueur*
(what makes it less obvious is that English does not have a plural form for an indefinite article *a*, using no article at all when a plural is indefinite.)

**Remark:**
Upon reflection I think we should also exclude the option that *des* here is an indefinite article, since *les utilisateurs de jets privés* is a definite phrase in French, implying the totality of these persons (unlike in English, where the first mentioning of this group could be indefinite, i.e., without an article.)

Answer (score 1):

The proper article is  "de". Only people with slackened speech  habits write "des".

- ([Kalmbach, grammaire](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/article-indefini.html)) L’ar­ti­cle in­dé­fi­ni pluriel devant adjectif an­té­po­sé
  **Règle générale**
  Quand l’ar­ti­cle in­dé­fi­ni pluriel (pas singulier, ni massif) *des* dé­ter­mi­ne un grou­pe no­mi­nal contenant un ad­jectif an­té­po­sé (qui précède le nom), il prend la for­me *de*.
  **Exceptions : fran­çais parlé**
  Dans le code écrit, la règle « *des* devient *de* devant ad­jec­tif an­té­po­sé » s’applique pra­ti­que­ment systématiquement (sauf dans le cas des mots com­po­sés pré­sen­té ci-dessus). Dans le fran­çais par­lé, on la néglige sou­vent :
  ■ Tu as acheté des beaux rideaux.
  ■ Au marché, j’ai trouvé des belles tomates.
  ■ Il y avait des petits bouleaux devant la maison.
  Mais devant un ad­jec­tif (ou un ad­ver­be) com­men­çant par une voyelle, on utilise très sou­vent la for­me *de*, mê­me dans le fran­çais parlé :
  ■ On a appris d’excellentes nouvelles !
  ■ On a vu d’énormes moustiques.
  ■ Ces deux petites entreprises sont d’assez grosses consommatrices d’électricité.

Comment: This is the right answer. However, as a native speaker, "Il y avait de petits bouleaux devant la maison." seems ungrammatical. I'm from Quebec. Not sure if this is a regional thing, but "des" seems necessary there. Can't quote a source, though.

Comment: @Jeffrey "De" can  sound  odd,  ungrammatical, as you say, but it is a matter of habits (that I  don't understand); I do have to ask myself sometimes whether this usage is natural or  not; this is so as it is not a regional thing in  France but a nation  wide pheomenon of disagreement between  the spoken  and the written language (due to the complexity I believe); that is to say that  we  hear "des" quite a lot instead of "de".